# How to INTERSECT two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, probability, intersection, independent-set

I have my data table `AC` in SQL Server with structure as:

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| AuthorID | CoAuthorID | Year  |
+----------+------------+-------+
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 266386     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 578338     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 721615     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  ...     |            |       |
|  ...     |            |       |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

I have to calculate the yearly `Conditional Probability` of `AuthorID` given `CoAuthorID` i.e.

`P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID)` = `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID) / P(CoAuthorID)`

while in year `2005` where it is an intersection operation.

Initially, for instance, `AuthorID = 677` and `CoAuthorID = 901706` and `Year = 2005`, I have tried this:

For `P(AuthorID)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AuthorID) FROM AC WHERE Year = 2005
```

It returns `390` so `P(AuthorID)` = `1/390`

For `P(CoAuthorID)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CoAuthorID) FROM AC WHERE AuthorID = 677 AND Year = 2005
```

It returns `1` so `P(CoAuthorID)` = `1/1`

For `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID)`:

```
SELECT * FROM AC WHERE AuthorID = 677 AND Year = 2005
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM AC WHERE CoAuthorID = 901706 AND Year = 2005
```

It returns 1 row as:

```
AuthorID    CoAuthorID  Year
----------------------------
677         901706      2005
```

Whereas there are 3 rows in data, it means `AuthorID` and `CoAuthorID` co-exists in data 3 times in `2005` means that these two Authors have contributed together 3 times in 2005. So,

1. What should be the value for `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID)`? Should it
   be `1` or `1/3`?
2. Also are other calculations are correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula is somewhat correct:

```
P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID) = P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID) / P(CoAuthorID)
```

Although you should specify the year constraint as well to be more exact:

```
P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year) = P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID|Year)/P(CoAuthorID|Year)
```

You give a calculation for `P(AuthorID)` (or actually `P(AuthorID|Year)`), but that term does not occur in the above formula, so it cannot be useful.

Secondly, you should not use `DISTINCT`. If there are many occurrences of the same author, then the probability of that author should be considered higher than that of another, less frequently occurring author. By using `DISTINCT` you would ignore these different frequencies, and attribute to each author the same probability. This cannot be the intention.

Instead you can identify these probabilities as follows:

#### `P(CoAuthorID|Year)`

Use this SQL to get that probability (between 0 and 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN CoAuthorID = 901706 THEN 1 
           END)       AS matching_records,
       COUNT(*)       AS considered_records,
       CAST(SUM(CASE 
              WHEN CoAuthorID = 901706 THEN 1 
           END) AS FLOAT)
           / COUNT(*) AS probability  
FROM   AC 
WHERE  Year = 2005
```

This returns in fact 3 values, while you only need the third. But it will help in analysing the result to also include the two first values.

The first value counts every occurrence of the given CoAuthorID in 2005 ("matching_records"), the second counts the *total* number of records for 2005 ("considered_records") and the third divides the first by the second to arrive at the probability.

In an extreme case, all of the 2005 records could have this CoAuthorID, and then the probability would return 1.

#### `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID|Year)`

Similarly, you can do the following for getting this probability:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN AuthorID = 677 AND CoAuthorID = 901706 THEN 1 
           END)       AS matching_records,
       COUNT(*)       AS considered_records,
       CAST(SUM(CASE 
              WHEN AuthorID = 677 AND CoAuthorID = 901706 THEN 1 
           END) AS FLOAT)
       / COUNT(*)     AS probability  
FROM   AC 
WHERE  Year = 2005
```

Notice the pattern that is emerging: in general, the constraint Y in `P(X|Y)` occurs in the `WHERE` clause, while X is represented in the `CASE WHEN` clause.

#### `P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year)`

Although you could use the results of the previous two queries, you could go for the more direct way, and use the pattern for `P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year)`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN AuthorID = 677 THEN 1 
           END)       AS matching_records,
       COUNT(*)       AS considered_records,
       CAST(SUM(CASE 
              WHEN AuthorID = 677 THEN 1 
           END) AS FLOAT)
       / COUNT(*)     AS probability  
FROM   AC 
WHERE  Year = 2005
AND    CoAuthorID = 901706
```

#### Answer to first question

> What should be the value for `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID)`? Should it be `1` or `1/3`?

As you have 3 rows in your data for which the AuthorId, CoAuthorID and Year match, `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID|Year)` is `3/num_records`, where `num_records` is the number or records for which Year is 2005.

Note that `INTERSECT` has as side-effect that it eliminates duplicates in the result. What I wrote above concerning `DISTINCT` also applies here: you need to count the duplicates when dealing with probabilities.

## Addendum: Some example results

Given this data:

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| AuthorID | CoAuthorID | Year  |
+----------+------------+-------+
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  677     | 901706     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 133112     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 266386     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 454557     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 534423     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 578338     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 721615     |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1016805    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361047    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1361320    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1395982    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
|  1359    | 1412785    |  2005 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

We can look at the following probabilities:

#### 1. `P(AuthorID=1359 | CoAuthorID=1361047 ∩ Year=2005)`

**Meaning:** *What is the probability for `AuthorID=1359` when it is a given that `CoAuthor=1361047` and `Year=2005`*

**Informally:** *In 2005, what fraction of collaborations of co-author 1361047 were with author 1359?*

Number of collaborations **considered**: 3, because this co-author only collaborated three times in 2005

Number of collaborations that **match**: 3, because this co-author collaborated three times with this author in 2005  (i.e. did not collaborate with anyone else)

**Probability:** 3/3 = 1.

#### 2. `P(AuthorID=1359 ∩ CoAuthorID=1361047 | Year=2005)`

**Meaning:** *What is the probability for a collaboration to be between `AuthorID=1359` and `CoAuthor=1361047` when it is a given that `Year=2005`*

**Informally:** *In 2005, what fraction of collaborations were between author 1359 and co-author 1361047?*

Number of collaborations **considered**: 31, because there were 31 collaborations in 2005

Number of collaborations that **match**: 3, because this author and co-author collaborated three times in 2005

**Probability:** 3/31.

#### 3. `P(CoAuthorID=1361047 | AuthorID=1359 ∩ Year=2005)`

**Meaning:** *What is the probability for `CoAuthor=1361047` when it is a given that `AuthorID=1359` and `Year=2005`*

**Informally:** *In 2005, what fraction of collaborations of author 1359 were with co-author 1361047?*

Number of collaborations **considered**: 28, because this author collaborated 28 times (with anyone) in 2005

Number of collaborations that **match**: 3, because this author collaborated three times with this co-author in 2005

**Probability:** 3/28.

### Observation

Notice how similar the above three predicates sound, but how different they really are. Exact wording is important. Take for instance this phrase:

*The probability of author A and co-author B being together in 2005*

Seeing this from the viewpoint of co-author B it is 100%, because this person did not co-author with any one else (case 1 above). But seeing this from the viewpoint of author A is different, since that person collaborated with many other co-authors also (case 3 above), and so the probability is smaller. But it can even be interpreted from no-one's viewpoint: then one could look at all collaborations in 2005 and see how many times it was between author A and co-author B (case 2). This is again another probability.

This shows that statements can easily be ambiguous, and care must be taken to be precise: what is assumed as a given? That must appear after the pipe symbol in the `P(X|Y)` notation.

Comment: @trincot--I have updated my data as if we sort data by `Year`, then as you see in data in `2005`, there are 3 `match_records` for `AuthorID` i.e. `1359` and `CoAuthorID` i.e. `133112`. Shouldn't it be divided with total records for `133112` against `2005` i.e. `28` as `3/28` for probability ?

Comment: @trincot--as you mentioned in answer at the end that, "`num_records` is the number or records for which `Year` is `2005`" but I think here we should add constraint as "`num_records` is the number or records for which `Year` is `2005` AND `AuthorID` is `677`" Am I right ?

Comment: For instance: if `AuthorID = 1359` and `CoAuthorID = 133112` and `Year = 2005` then `P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year)` will be:  
`SELECT SUM(CASE 
              WHEN AuthorID = 1359 AND CoAuthorID = 133112 THEN 1 
     END)                AS matching_records,
       
    COUNT(*)                AS considered_records,

       CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN AuthorID = 1359 AND CoAuthorID = 133112 THEN 1 
    END) AS FLOAT) / 
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) AS probability  

FROM   AC 
WHERE  Year = 2005
AND    AuthorID = 1359`  
It'll give `3/28` as probability.
Isn't it correct?

Comment: Those are two different things. *num_records* was about `P(AuthorID ∩ CoAuthorID|Year)`, but your comment is about `P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year)`. `P(AuthorID|CoAuthorID ∩ Year)` means: *what is the probability to find this AuthorID, given a specific CoAuthorID and year*. So what you have as pre-condition is at the right of the pipe. This translates to a `WHERE` clause and sets *num_records*. That is the set of data you are going to look at for determining the probability. You then must count the instances of what occurs at the left of the pipe and divide it by *num_records*.

Comment: @trincot--But all of the probabilities which I have calculated are almost same i.e. `1` because the value of numerator and denominator in the formula returns same value so far, for the values of AuthorID and CoAuthorID's which I have checked yet

Comment: Could you somehow provide the data, so I could look at it? Or can you give an example based on the data you provided in the question only?

Comment: @trincot--Yeah why not but it is in csv format, How to transfer it to you?

Comment: @trincot--My confusion is only that we should take `AuthorID` n `CoAuthorID` in a specific `Year` as `Matched_Records` and divide it by number of times that `AuthorID` exists in that specific `Year` as `Considered_Records` for `Probability`, what you say?

Comment: @trincot--For example, author `A` and co-author `B` collaborates `3` times in `2005`, and author `A` has **total** `28` collaborations in `2005` so probability of author `A` and author `B` being together in 2005 will be `3/28`. What do you say?

Comment: @trincot--would you please like to look at my last most comment and suggest ?

Comment: 3/28 would be `P(CoAuthorID | AuthorID ∩ Year)`, or more precisely with the values: `P(CoAuthorID=B | AuthorID=A ∩ Year=2005)`, i.e. *the probability to find CoAuthorID B if it is a given that AuthorID=A and Year=2005*. That you should get with `SELECT ... CASE WHEN CoAuthorID = B THEN 1 END ... WHERE AuthorID = A AND Year = 2005`.

Comment: But *the probability for author A and coauthor B to work together in 2005* is a fuzzy predicate. It could be interpreted as *the probability for author A to have worked together with coauthor B in 2005* or as *the probability for coauthor B to have worked together with author A in 2005* -- it's not the same. The first is `P(Coauthor B | Author A ∩ Year 2005)`; the second is `P(Coauthor A | Author B ∩ Year 2005)`. Then `P(Coauthor A ∩ Author B | Year 2005)` is still something else. That latter means *the probability that any collaboration in 2005 is one between author A and coauthor B.*

Comment: @trincot--We actually want to calculate `P(TargetObject | AttributeObject)` i.e. `P(Author | CoAuthor)`, so we have to calculate the conditional probability of _TargetObject_ given _AttributeObject_ actually. So you mean that `3/28` can't be the probability of _TargetObject_ given _AttributeObject_ ?

Comment: I added an addendum to my answer. Please have a look,  and feel free to come back if you need more clarification.

Comment: @trincot--Bundles of thanks your gratitude, its almost clear now but as you mentioned in the second last paragraph as: "_But seeing this from the viewpoint of author A is different, since that person collaborated with many other co-authors also (case 3 above), and so the probability is smaller_" Is **case 3** is from viewpoint of _AuthorID_?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that. If I were author A and asked myself which fraction of my 2005-collaborations was with co-author B, the question corresponds to case 3.

Comment: @trincot--Right, then its mean case 3 will provide the _probability_ value for _Author_ (i.e. you if you are author) and this _probability_ value will not be for _CoAuthor_? If this is so, that's what I needed. Now in my case, if _P(Target | Attribute)_ is as _Target = Author_ and _Attribute = CoAuthor_, then how will I represent it in form as in **case 3**

Comment: Be careful how you phrase it. I would not call case 3 *the probability value for Author*. That is ambiguous. Just make sure you read the description of case 3. It is all there. I don't really understand the concepts target and attribute you use, but maybe it is just the way the parts of the P-notation are named. Maybe also read about the pipe symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability

Answer (score 0):

> EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t
> output by the right input query.
>
> INTERSECT returns distinct rows that are output by both the left and
> right input queries.

`DISTINCT`, Karl.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.120).aspx